# Can't install VirtualBox in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

It seems to be an access right problem. I can't find the solution. I just try to grant full access (administrator) but it doesn't work.
[image]

Comment: Did you run setup as Administrator?

Comment: Using Win 7 32 or 64-bit? The install file looks to be for 32-bit.

Comment: @Andrejs: Yes, I tried, same problem.
$SgtOJ: Win7 32bit.

Comment: What is in the path that is specified in the error box?

Comment: I don't know, I just click "Next" and "Install", perhaps VirtualBox used that path to store temporary files.

Comment: have you tried moving the MSI to a different directory?

Answer (score 2):

Rather late in the day, but it might help someone else

I (just) had this problem  - checking the temp folder showed the file was there, but any amount of trying failed. Then I "took ownership" of the temp folder and contents, and everything went fine. Taking ownership comes upon my x64 PC when I right click on a file or folder

Had a sneaky feeling the take ownership option was non standard - [this link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-take-ownership-to-explorer-right-click-menu-in-vista/) shows how to get it.

For completeness, here's the registry key which adds that

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\runas]
@="Take Ownership"
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /c takeown /f \"%1\" && icacls \"%1\" /grant administrators:F"
"IsolatedCommand"="cmd.exe /c takeown /f \"%1\" && icacls \"%1\" /grant administrators:F"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas]
@="Take Ownership"
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /c takeown /f \"%1\" /r /d y && icacls \"%1\" /grant administrators:F /t"
"IsolatedCommand"="cmd.exe /c takeown /f \"%1\" /r /d y && icacls \"%1\" /grant administrators:F /t"
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are running the program directly from the browser.  Try saving the file first then right click the file and run as Administrator.

I also notice that the error box is referring to 4.0.8 while you appear to be installing 4.1.2.  Hopefully saving this off to a download folder will clear that up.

Comment: No, I downloaded VirtualBox and installed offlinely. The browser in the picture is irrelevant.